# Django Static Files(CSS) don't link with template

Tags: css, django, django-staticfiles

Just as the title says, static files somehow are not loading up in my template. I've tried working on it and looking at similar StackOverflow questions but I can't find a solution. I tried debugging it using browser's dev tools.

I tried opening the CSS file from there but it just leads me to this error. This leads me to the conclusion that Django doesn't seem to find `base.css` inside the static folder. I've already done `manage.py collectstatic` so there shouldn't be a problem. Thanks!

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static/base.css
'static\base.css' could not be found

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

**settings.py**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

**template**

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
```

edit: reverted back `{% static 'static/base.css' %}` to `{% static 'css/base.css' %}`

Comment: probably **`{% static 'base.css' %}`** instead of `{% static 'static/base.css' %}` ?

Comment: My apologies ```{% static 'static/base.css' %}``` was one the things I tried doing to make it work lol. But earlier I have already tried out ```{% static 'base.css' %}``` and ```{% static 'css/base.css' %}``` earlier and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly, you have to correct the settings.py :**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Then, lets say, you stored your **css file** in **static/base.css**
Now, write, `{% static 'base.css' %}` because django by-default look up for your static files in your app so you dont have to include static path.

Comment: Thank you!! Can I ask you more about the difference between ```STATICFILES_DIR``` and ```STATIC_ROOT```?.

Comment: Static_Root is the path from where you want to serve your files when production.And Static_Dirs is the path that does serve static files when development. :)